# Online Algorithm for Standard Deviation Proof

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, standard-deviation, online-algorithm

I saw this algorithm in an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978667/online-algorithm-for-calculating-standard-deviation).

Does this correctly calculate standard deviation? Can someone walk me through why this works mathematically? Preferably working back from this formula:

[image]

```
public class Statistics {

    private int n;
    private double sum;
    private double sumsq;

    public void reset() {
        this.n = 0;
        this.sum = 0.0;
        this.sumsq = 0.0;
    }

    public synchronized void addValue(double x) {
        ++this.n;
        this.sum += x;
        this.sumsq += x*x;
    }

    public synchronized double calculateMean() {
        double mean = 0.0;
        if (this.n > 0) {
            mean = this.sum/this.n;
        }
        return mean;
    }

    public synchronized double calculateStandardDeviation() {
        double deviation = 0.0;
        if (this.n > 1) {
            deviation = Math.sqrt((this.sumsq - this.sum*this.sum/this.n)/(this.n-1));
        }
        return deviation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [proof on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Definition_of_population_values) at the start of the section I linked to.

[image]

By the way, I remember from somewhere that calculating this way can produce more error.
As you can see `this.sumsq` can become huge.
Whereas calculating the normal way always has smaller intermediate values.

Anyway, I do use this online calculation a lot, because most of the time error didn't matter that much.

Comment: Bingo.  If you do start caring about numerical stability, you might work out a two-step update; to get (k+1)Var<sub>k+1</sub> from k Var<sub>k</sub>, add (x<sub>k+1</sub> - mu<sub>k</sub>)<sup>2</sup> then work out an update so that you get the sum of squares of differences from the new mean instead of the old.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this on the wikipedia page, but this totally make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe population standard deviation would substitute N-1 for N in that formula, because there's one degree of freedom less when the mean is given.  I'm not a statistician, so I don't have the proof.

The formula is correct - standard deviation is the square root of the mean variance.